# Random numbers from one array to another

Tags: c, arrays, random

I am programming for an embedded board to light up 4 LED's (out of 8).
I want to randomise the ones that are lit, and repeat this process. 
Basically, by copying the values from an array of set numbers (the LED bit values), making them random, and inserting them into another array. The second array needs unique values (ie the same 4 LED's, but in a unique random pattern). I need to replicate this x number of times, hence the main while loop.

Currently, I get repeated numbers in the second array. I believe this is because the nested for loops are not breaking properly. I have tried break, making the for loop counters (i/j) maximum value (this causes an infinite loop), and even goto.

So far to no avail. Any corrections or advice on a better way to solve this appreciated!

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));                  //Set seed random number
    int ledORIGINAL[4] = { 2,4,6,8 };   //Array of defined numbers to use
    int led[4] = { 0,0,0,0 };           //Empty array (set to 0's)
    int rIndex=0, ledIndex=0, loop=0;   //Index variables
    bool originalNum = false;           //Boolean flag to find original number

    while (loop < 2) {                  //Set how many random arrays you need

        while (ledIndex < 4) {          //Repeat util all 4 array slots filled
            rIndex = rand() % 4;        //Get a random index number
            if (led[ledIndex] == 0) {               //If the array slot is empty
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {       //Nested for loops to check number is not already in array
                    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                        if (led[i] != ledORIGINAL[j]) {
                            originalNum = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            originalNum = false;        //Boolean flag set to false, no need to search further
                            //i= 4;                     //Set i to 4 to break outer loop
                            //j = 4;                        //Set j to 4 to break inner loop
                            break;
                            //goto PLACE;

                        }
                    }
                }
                //PLACE:
                if (originalNum) {
                    led[ledIndex] = ledORIGINAL[rIndex];
                    ledIndex++;
                }

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            std::cout << led[i];
            led[i] = 0;
        }
        ledIndex = 0;
        loop++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create an array of length 8, with 4 zeros and 4 ones. Then [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) to select the LEDs to light.

Comment: I need to keep the numbers so I can shift them later, rather than using actual bits

Comment: What keeps you from FY-shuffling the array, i.e. using a known algorithm for the purpose?

Comment: you claim that the posted code is C, however, it contains: `std::cout << led[i];`  which is a C++ statement.

Comment: regarding: `    break;`  This only exits the inner `for()` loop, not the outer `for()` loop

Comment: I got it working with the Fisher-Yates algorithm. Thanks for the suggestion @user3386109. Still unsure how to break out from the two nested for loops though.

Answer (score 0):

strongly suggest replacing the posted code with:

```
struct fourLeds = { int led[4] };
const struct fourLeds ledTable[] =
{
    {8, 7, 6, 5},
    {8, 7, 6, 4},
    {8, 7, 6, 3},
    {8, 7, 6, 2},
    {8, 7, 6, 1},

    {8, 6, 5, 4},
    {8, 6, 5, 3},
    {8, 6, 5, 2},
    {8, 6, 5, 1},

    {8, 6, 4, 3},
    {8, 6, 4, 2},
    {8, 6, 4, 1},

    {8, 6, 3, 2},
    {8, 6, 3, 1},

    {8, 6, 2, 1},

    {8, 5, 4, 3},
    {8, 5, 4, 2},
    {8, 5, 4, 1],

    {8, 4, 3, 2},
    {8, 4, 3, 1},

    {8, 3, 2, 1}, 

    {7, 6, 5, 4},
    {7, 6, 5, 3},
    {7, 6, 5, 2},
    {7, 6, 5, 1},
    ....
    {7, 5, 4, 3},
    {7, 5, 4, 2},
    {7, 5, 4, 1},
    ....
    {7, 5, 2, 1},

    {7, 4, 3, 2},
    {7. 4, 3, 1},

    {7, 4, 2, 1},

    {7, 3, 2, 1},

    {6, 5. 4, 3},
    {6, 5, 4, 2},
    {6, 5, 4, 1},

    {6, 4, 3, 2},
    {6, 4, 3, 1},

    {6, 3, 2, 1},

    {5, 4, 3, 2},
    {5, 4, 3, 1},

    {5, 4, 2, 1},

    {5, 3, 2, 1},

    {4, 3, 2, 1},
};

int selection = rand() %( sizeof(ledTable) / sizeof(ledTable[0]) );
then output  `ledTable[ selection ]`
```